# how to disable the Paypal Credit payment method in magento2?

Tags: paypal, magento-2.0

Magento 2 Enabled the *PayPal express checkout payment method* in my site but in front end product view page, cart page, checkout payment information it displayed PayPal express checkout and PayPal credit options. How to disable the PayPal credit payment method in Magento 2?

[image: checkout page screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

go to Configuration> payment methods> paypal configuration, and next to "Enable PayPal Credit" select no

Answer (score 1):

If it's not manage from backend so you can remove from file. Simply **$_shouldRender** define **false** in

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/Block/Bml/Shortcut.php

at line no. **25**.

```
protected $_shouldRender = false;
```

Thanks :)